# Can dart Mockito mock abstract classes?

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

I am trying to add some unit tests to my dart/flutter library, and one of the dependencies of my unit-under-test is an abstract class:

```
abstract class LoginService {
    Future<void> login(String username, String password);
}
```

When I add `@GenerateMocks([LoginService])` to my test file and run `build_runner`, it fails with:

```
mockito:mockBuilder on test/login_test.dart:  Invalid @GenerateMocks annotation: The GenerateMocks "classes" argument is missing, includes an unknown type, or includes an extension
```

But if I manually type:

```
class MockLoginService extends Mock implements LoginService {}
```

there is no compilation error.

If I change `LoginService` to no longer be `abstract` (with some dummy implementation), then the mock succeeds.

Any ideas? I've checked dart Mockito's GitHub issues but can't find anyone with this issue.

Comment: Do you have any concrete classes that inherit from `LoginService` (other than the mock class)?

Comment: @Abion47 no it's purely abstract at this stage.

Comment: I'm not at a place where I can run my own tests at the moment, but my first suspicion is that since you don't have any classes that inherit from the abstract class, Dart's tree-shaking is removing it from existence. Try creating a concrete class and see if the mock_builder will work on the abstract class after that.

Comment: @Abion47 seems to have been exactly that! After creating a random impl class, it works. Maybe you want to submit it as an "answer" so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the [example code from the mockito_builder repo](https://github.com/digitalrmdy/mockito-builder/blob/master/example/test/usecase/example_use_case.dart) is any indication, it seems like in order to build mocks of abstract classes, there needs to be a concrete implementation of that class somewhere.

My guess is that, when the Dart code is compiled (JIT or otherwise) and loaded into the build_runner, tree-shaking will see that the abstract class has no implementations nor any other references of any kind, so it removes the class from the compiled code. By the time build_runner can do its thing, the abstract class effectively no longer exists.

So in theory, all you need to do is make a placeholder implementation of your class and the code generation will work:

```dart
abstract class LoginService {
  Future<void> login(String username, String password);
}

class LoginServiceImpl extends LoginService {
  @override
  Future<void> login(String username, String password) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used mockito to mock for an abstract repository. E.g;

```
@GenerateMocks([NumberTriviaRepository])
void main(){
  final mockNumberTriviaRepository = MockNumberTriviaRepository();
}
```

Use build_runner to generate files;

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```